# action does not wait till function call ends

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

I have 2 actions that i put in a sequence. In the first action I am calling a method to calculate the new waiting time for the next action. The next action is just a wait for this duration, but the second action always executes straight away, so the time must be 0. I debugged it and in the method spawnFlowers i get the time returned as 3.5 seconds.

these are my 2 actions

```
let spawnFlowerAction = SKAction.run {
            self.WaitTime = self.calculateWaitingTime()
        }
let waitForNewFlower = SKAction.wait(forDuration: self.WaitTime)
```

I execute it this way:

```
        let spawnSeq = SKAction.sequence([spawnFlowerAction, waitForNewFlower])
        let spawnRepeat = SKAction.repeat(spawnSeq, count: 4)
        self.run(spawnRepeat)
```

Result: 4 times spawned without waiting, printing 4 different calculated times in the console from the calculateWaitingTime function (in which the spawning happens)

What is a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is trying to dynamically change the values used within SKActions after the action has been created. For example when your `WaitTime` variable changes while running the `spawnFlowerAction`, the `waitForNewFlower` Action's wait time won't change dynamically because it doesn't reference `WaitTime`. Instead its wait value is whatever your variable `WaitTime` was when you declared `let waitForNewFlower = SKAction.wait(forDuration: self.WaitTime)` (Which I'm guessing was initially 0). Same concept goes with your other two spawn actions.

I usually use the dispatch Queue for things like these, but to use SKActions here's a function. Just call it once and input the number of times you want it to repeat.

```
func spawnRepeat(count: Int) {

    //Put whatever code to spawn flower here
    print("SPAWN FLOWER")

    if count > 1 {
        //Recalculate WaitTime
        WaitTime = calculateWaitingTime()
        let waitAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: WaitTime)
        run(waitAction, completion: { self.spawnRepeat(count: count - 1) })
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try this tomorrow and mark your answer if its working thank you lots :)